# Does each queue on ZeroMQ require it's own port?

Tags: node.js, zeromq

We are looking to build a facade in nodejs that will accept requests from a client and then farm out the requests to a number of services using request/reply pattern to a number of different backend services. We want these requests held on individual queues in the event that one of the backend services is down. From initially reading of the ZeroMQ docs, it appears each queue is bound to its own port. When sending a message to a socket, there doesn't appear to be a way of naming a queue/topic to send to. 
Is there a one-one mapping between ports and queues?

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 0):

ZeroMQ doesn't have the concept of "queues" or "topics". Your application consists of tasks, connected across some protocol, e.g. tcp://, and sending each other messages in various patterns. In your example one task will bind to an address:port and the workers will connect to it. The sender then sends requests to its socket, which deals them out to workers.

The best way to learn ZeroMQ is to work through at least the first couple of chapters of the Guide, before you design your own application. Many of the existing messaging concepts you're familiar with disappear into simpler patterns with ZeroMQ.